# COUNTIFS Function With Complex Criteria

Tags: excel, date, criteria

I'm trying to create a formula to return a count of records meeting multiple criteria and I've come up with the following so far which is not working but demonstrates a bit of what I'm after,

```
=COUNTIFS(div_cde2,"UG", yr_cde2,C6&"*"-6, trm_cde2,"10", cohort_cde2,C6&"*"-6&"YY"&"FBT")
```

I want to define more complex criteria to accomplish the following:

1. Subtract 6 years from the 4-digit year in `C6`
2. Retain only the last 2 digits of the year resulting from that calculation
3. Add the letters `"FBF"` to the two digit year to create the criteria
   needed for the `cohort_cde` defined range.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should answer the questions you have.

1. Subtract 6 years from the 4-digit year in `C6`

   `C6 - 6`
2. Retain only the last 2 digits of the year resulting from that calculation

`RIGHT(C6-6, 2)`

3. Add the letters `"FBF"` to the two digit year to create the criteria needed for the `cohort_cde` defined range.

`RIGHT(C6-6, 2) & "FBF"`

Put all these things together and you get (formula that OP ultimately used)

`=COUNTIFS(div_cde2,"UG",yr_cde2,C6-6,trm_cde2,"10",cohort_cde2,RIGHT(C6-6, 2)&"FBF")`

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much...I had actually found the "RIGHT" function and was trying to fit it in every which way, but couldn't do it until I saw your solution!  I did have to put the "FBF" at the end instead of the beginning.  Here's the formula in full that ended up working with your gracious assistance.         =COUNTIFS(div_cde2,"UG",yr_cde2,C6-6,trm_cde2,"10",cohort_cde2,RIGHT(C6-6, 2)&"FBF")